# Error in catchment delineation process

Tags: qgis

While delineating catchment in QGIS using Upslope Area, error:`could not create index insufficient memory` prompted and software got hang again and again. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate of [Kernel Density Error in QGIS Processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72779/kernel-density-error-in-qgis-processing)

Catchment delineation tools generally need to load the full raster into memory.  You can get around this by:

- working on a subset,
- using swap (which may be very slow),
- reducing the resolution to get a general answer for the full dataset, then working on the coarser catchments using a higher resolution.

See also https://sagatutorials.wordpress.com/trouble-shootoing/